# || ,| , && inside an IF statement

Tags: c#

i want to do the following IF statement,

```
if (checkID.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txtCheck.Text)) 
    && drop == 319020000 
    || currentFloor[id][0].checkFlag == 1)
```

what i want to check here it the following thing:

i want to check if this whole statement is true

```
checkID.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txtCheck.Text)) && drop == 319020000`
```

or this statment:

```
currentFloor[id][0].checkFlag == 1
```

If 1 of them is true it should go inside the loop.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: put first two checks in braces?

Comment: What makes you think you're doing something wrong?  What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Is it actually going wrong? In C#, == binds tighter than && which binds tighter than ||, and those rules, according to my reading, gets you what you say you want with the code you've posted.

Comment: I personally do not *want* to remember which goes first, `&&` or `||`. So I always add `()` around the part that should go first - that way I'm sure.

Comment: What loop?  Try to formulate a question in terms of what you expected and what actually happens. Make the effort to write a small standalone program that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `if` is composed properly, you have problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses, you have many operators at the same level and precedence may be killing you

```
if ((checkID.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txtCheck.Text)) && drop == 319020000)
    || currentFloor[id][0].checkFlag == 1)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

;)

Comment: Correct link, wrong conclusion. Try to state which rule would be helped by `()`

Comment: The fact is that I always enclose every comparison in parentheses (thanks Phill for the editting). As someone stated above, I do not want to remeber about precedence, so for me a good practice is to use parentheses as much as I need. As the question was formuled, I would use this code :

if ( ( checkID.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txtCheck.Text)) && drop == 319020000)  || (currentFloor[id][0].checkFlag == 1)  )

To be sure I am really getting what I want

Comment: Agreed that the  `()` are a good practice but they can not be the answer here.

Comment: Well, the question is kind of "vast" : "What am i doing wrong here?". I just assumed that the if clause was not behaving as expected and I advised to use parentheses just to ensure that the problem was not in the actual comparison.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use additional parentheses like follows,

```
if ((checkID.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txtCheck.Text)) && drop == 319020000) || currentFloor[id][0].checkFlag == 1)
```

Comment: One of about 10 answers about adding parenthesis but `a && b || c` is exactly the same as `(a && b) || c`